# Passing dollar sign ($) to function

Tags: jquery

I'm working with some jquery that someone else wrote that looks like the following code and was wondering why the dollar sign should be passed to the javascript updateTextareas function.

It is using 2 arguments: $, $textareas.  It seems to work fine with only one argument ($textareas).

I'm trying to figure out why the author would pass in the $ as the first argument in the updateTextareas function below:

```
( function($) 
{
    // why would the first argument ($) need to be passed here?
    function updateTextareas($, $textareas)
    {
        $textareas.each(function()
        {
            alert($(this).val());
        });
    }   

    // document ready
    $(function()
    {
        updateTextareas($, $('textarea.bio') );
});
} )(jQuery);
```

Comment: It simply allows the use of jQuery as `$` without conflicting with other possible libs

Comment: [This "old" article](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2008/12/what-heck-is-function-jquery.html) I found may help, tho, as mentioned in in answers below, it's highly unnecessary in new jQuery. See also [jQuery.noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

Comment: People .. he's asking about the `$` in here `function updateTextareas($, $textareas)`

Comment: @KaloyanIvanov we got that, and the answer's still the same. it's just passing jquery as $ with no conflict. but for many reasons, this is deprecated.

Comment: @SpYk3HH But what would be the point of passing `$` to a function when `$` is already defined and accessible?

Comment: Honestly, scratch that old code and just rewrite it yourself. That whole thing is rewritten as easy as `function updateTextareas($this) { $this.each(function(i) { alert($(this).val()); }); }; $.noConflict(); jQuery(document).ready(function($) { updateTextareas($('.bio')); });`

Comment: One last thing you might want to look at for whatever you are doing: [jQuery.change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/)

Comment: @Joe its an OLD practice. It used to be on their docs, before their facelift. It was a common practice to ensure "no conflict". I don't write the jQuery library and have only picked apart about a 1/4 of it, so I couldn't begin to tell you the "absolute" reason, but I have reference from what "used" to be listed on their docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is that this would allow you to pass a "façade" or another function who'll act like jQuery. This could be used in unit test for example.

But, honestly, that's a bit of an overhead and I wouldn't recommend doing so. It's mostly useless as is and there's easier way of achieving the same for unit test.

Comment: And what is that easier way?

Comment: @DavidThomas just mock the jQuery function when you're testing.

Answer (score 3):

At the point of function definition:

```
function updateTextareas($, $textareas)
```

The value of `$` is already defined in the current scope (passed as an argument to the outer function), so passing it here again is completely useless and can be omitted.

Btw, it may have once been necessary when the function was defined outside of the `(function($) { ... }(jQuery));` wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

Its so that that code like this or other plugins can work with other Javascript libraries that might already be using the dollar-sign. In which case without flexible support for re-naming jQuery (basically) you'd have collisions.

Sure, the author could have originally not used `$` at all and just used `jQuery` everywhere and that would also skirt the whole issue - but the nice thing about using `$` when you can is that its short and terse.

Comment: Not sure about that. He's already passing jQuery as $ into the IIFE, so there's no risk of name collision there.

Comment: I think the OP is confused as to why the code author is passing `$` as an argument to `updateTextareas()` when it's unnecessary to do so. `$`  could just be used as any possible naming collision has already been avoided with `(function($){})(jQuery);`

Comment: Thanks very much, still a little confused though. I thought that since the updateTextareas function was already within a self-invoking function which is using the $ to represent JQuery, that there would be no possibility of $ conflicting with other js libraries using the $.  Sorry, just saw the other 2 comments above after posting this.